# PowerShell after FilesystemChecker to copy variable

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to copy some files that might be newly added to a folder
 after the file has been monitored and event generated. But I am having
 problem to copy those files added to the folder, any help with the
 below script to copy the variable $name. It might be a loop process,
 but just could not know how to copy the new files added to the folder.
 Code below....

```
$folder = 'C:\RDF' 
$filter = '*.RDF'                             
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName'}   

    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
    Out-File -FilePath C:\RDF\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"} 
    # Copy-Item C:\RDF\$name -destination C:\RDF\Move_temp
    Copy-Item -Path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -Destination  C:\RDF\Move_temp -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. The copy code is outside the Curly brackets

```
$folder = 'C:\RDF'  
$filter = '*.RDF'  

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 


$targetdirectory = "C:\RDF\Move_temp"
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 

Out-File -FilePath C:\RDF\output.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"

Copy-Item $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath  -Destination $targetdirectory -Force

 }
```